# Can Krazy Glue be used as a sealant?

Tags: materials, adhesive

The rubber casing for my iPhone cable has frayed and split near the phone port, and I would like to seal it somehow to stop the split from spreading further. Would Krazy Glue be an effective sealant? I've heard that superglue can eat away at some materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where a cable enters a connector is a point strain, point strains are remarkably prone to failure. I would not use glue at all particularly a rigid glue like super glue. I would use dental floss or string, and caulk or a curable plastic putty.

To begin take a length of string about two foot long and fold it in half place the edge of your connector (the par directly opposite from where the cable enters the connector) in the fold of the string. Tye a couple knots around the connector ending with each end of the string  next to the cord, but on opposites sides. A drop or two of glue to hold the string to the connector body may be needed. Push the cable gently into the connector to relieve strain. alternating the two string tails, tie a series of half hitches up the cable. Mask off the connector edge. Cover the connector body and the cord end that is tied with caulk. Let cure. Remove the mask, trim the excess caulk cut the string from the connector edge and trim the string ends. Will outlast your phone.

Comment: This answer really needs some illustrations.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search of [PVC](https://www.spilltech.com/wcsstore/SpillTechUSCatalogAssetStore/Attachment/documents/ccg/CBOOM.pdf), the main coating for most cables, corrosion information turns up some answers:

1. [Cyanoacrylate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate), the main component of Krazy glue is not listed in most corrosion guides.
2. [Acrylates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylate), the main type of material that consist of most "super glues", are not well supported for PVC (see the corrosion guide above).
3. [PVC primer](https://web.archive.org/web/20170215054923/http://www.oatey.com/msds/msds62-purple-primer-pvc-cpvc2.pdf) and bonder is typically sold at hardware stores - this would be ideal as it is designed to work and bond PVC together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cyanoacrylate but I would use a "toughened" super glue that has a rubber modifier in its chemical formula to make it less brittle. Also , super glue vapors have a tendency to blush surfaces with a white film so I would carefully mask off every surface except the repair area with masking tape before you apply any glue. You can use super glue accelerator to instantly cure the glue, very convenient for building up super glue to any thickness you like.